# Randomly use a Comparison operator?

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators

I have an array with a list of comparison operators.  How can I randomly select one to use?  I tried the following but failed.

```
from random import choice
logi = ["<",">","=="]
n=20
n2 = choice(range(1,100))
if n choice(logi) n2: print n2
```

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html):

```
import operator
logi = [operator.lt, operator.gt, operator.eq]

...

if choice(logi)(n, n2):
    print n2
```

Comment: Curse you and your quicker fingers! ;)

Answer (score 5):

You want to take not the textual representation of the operator, but some functional representation. For this, the [operator module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) is perfect:

```
import operator

logi = [operator.lt, operator.gt, operator.eq]
```

Then, you can just apply this function using `choice`:

```
n = 20
n2 = choice(range(1,100))
if choice(logi)(n, n2): 
    print n2
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can -- using the `operator` module.

```
from random import choice
from operator import lt, gt, eq

logi = [lt, gt, eq]
n=20
n2 = choice(range(1,100))
if choice(logi)(n, n2): print n2
```

Answer (score 1):

Yaw!

As **@sweeneyrod** said, I have to warn. It is ***not*** recommended to use `eval`, especially with user input. It is just a **possible** way to do that, but ***not* recommended one**

```
from random import choice
logi = ["<",">","=="]
n=20
n2 = choice(range(1,100))
if eval("n%sn2"%choice(logi)): print n2
```

Or

```
import operator

logi = [operator.lt, operator.gt, operator.eq]
n=20
n2 = choice(range(1,100))
if choice(logi)(n, n2): print n2
```

Comment: The first one is a very bad idea, as using `eval` is unsafe.

Comment: @sweeneyrod - Eh, I wouldn't go as far as to say "very bad".  It's an _ok_ idea.  Using `eval` is only dangerous with user input.  This is a completely self-contained program though.  Still, it _does_ encourage the use of something that can become very bad quite quickly...

Comment: @iCodez I'd say it is still a very dangerous habit that should be discouraged, because of the amount of damage that can occur when it _is_ dangerous. As an analogy, I'd say using `eval` is like playing Russian roulette. With no user input, it's like the gun isn't loaded, so technically it's safe, but because of the amount of damage that could occur if that wasn't the case you get into the habit of doing it anyway.

Comment: @sweeneyrod, I know it is not the best way to do this, but I just posted ***possible*** ways to do this. It doesn't mean they are preffered

Comment: @Vik2015 I understand (I didn't downvote you), I just thought that anyone considering using the first one, and therefore `eval` ought to have some sort of warning.